# ifで文法が合っているのにinvaind syntaxがでる

Tags: python

Pythonで適当に遊んでいたのですが、if文を使ってy/n分岐させようとするとinvaind syntaxがでます。

ネットでエラーについて調べると全角スペースやコロンのつけ忘れなどと書かれていますが、そのような文法ミスは見た感じありません。

どうすればいいでしょうか？

コード:

```
check = input("y/n");
if check == "y";
 print(num+nnuumm)
else;
```

はじめてのstackoverflowでコード表示の仕方が分かりませんが許してください。

エラーの行は

```
if check == "y";
```

です。

Answer (score 4):

`if` 文の最後は `;` (セミコロン) ではなく `:` (コロン) を記述します。(`else` も同様)

**記述例:**

```
if 条件式:
```